# javascript "APP" in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html

I have basically created a 'calculator' using javascript which works offline. That means, it uses the installed browser as the program's interpreter. The script is mobile-friendly if that is a right terminology. How can I distribute the html file which just contains javascript and basically html as an app in various platforms? Do I need to have some fron-end in Java or Obj-C or some native language interface depending on the platform? How can I make javascript behave actually like an app?

Apologies if this is a basic question but I could not find any convincing answers.

Comment: i don't see what native apps can do for a calculator that a manifest and fastclick won't do for the html version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).